# Is the set open with respect to the metric d

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X=\mathbb{R}\times (\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}})\cup \{(0,0)\} $ und consider
$$ d: \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R},\\[10pt](x,y)\mapsto \begin{cases}\|x-y\|_2,\qquad \text{if } \{x,y\} \text{ linear dependent}\\[10pt]\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2,\ \ \text{if } \{x,y\} \text{ linear independent}\end{cases} $$

I want to show that $ X $ is open with respect to $ d $  but with $ (0,0) $ I have problems finding an $ \varepsilon>0 $ such that $ B_{\varepsilon}((0,0))\subseteq X $.

For all $ (x,y)\in X\setminus{\{(0,0)\}} $ I chose $ 0<\varepsilon<\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ and I consider the ball $$ B_{\varepsilon}((x,y))=\{(x',y')\in \mathbb{R}^2:d((x,y),(x',y'))<\varepsilon\} $$ with $ (x',y')\in B_{\varepsilon}((x,y)) $ arbitrary. Now I do case distinction:

1.) $\{(x,y),(x',y')\}$ linear dependent. The I get at first $ (x',y')=\lambda\cdot (x,y) $ for one $ \lambda\in \mathbb{R} $ and it is $ d((x,y),(x',y'))=|1-\lambda|\cdot \|(x,y)\|_2=|1-\lambda|\cdot \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\varepsilon<\sqrt{x^2+y^2} $ which means that $ 0<\lambda<2 $. So $ (x',y')\neq (0,0) $ and it applies $ (x',y')\in X $.

2.) $\{(x,y),(x',y')\}$ linear independent. It applies
$$ d((x,y),(x',y'))=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}\stackrel{x'\neq\lor y'\neq 0}{>} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}>\varepsilon>0 $$
which means this case does not occur.

Comment: I think $ (0,0) $ is not an inner point. Let $ \varepsilon>0 $ arbitrary and consider $ (x',y')\in B_{\varepsilon}((0,0)) $. Then $ \{(0,0),(x',y')\} $ is linear dependent and it applies $d((0,0),(x',y'))=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}<\varepsilon $. So is also true for example $ (x',y')=(\frac{\varepsilon}{2},0)\in (\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0\}})\times \{(0,0)\} $